# How to add image after and before the text of ColumnLabelProvider

Tags: java, swt, jface

I have tried by extending ColumnLabelProvider and used below code to the checkbox tree viewer

```
getTree().addListener(SWT.PaintItem, new Listener() {
            @Override
            public void handleEvent(Event event) {
                TreeItem treeItem = (TreeItem) event.item;
                ConfigTreeViewNode item = (ConfigTreeViewNode) treeItem.getData();
                if (!(item instanceof ConfigTreeViewNodeConfig)) {
                    return;
                }
                ConfigTreeViewNodeConfig configNode = (ConfigTreeViewNodeConfig) item;
                if (configNode.getValidationMessage() == null) {
                    return; // not evaluated yet
                }

                ConfigTreeViewLabelProvider labelProvider = (ConfigTreeViewLabelProvider) getLabelProvider();
                Image image = labelProvider.getConversionValidationStateImage(configNode.getValidationMessage());
                int x = event.x + event.width + 2; // give small margin
                int itemHeight = getTree().getItemHeight();
                int imageHeight = image.getBounds().height;
                int y = event.y + (itemHeight - imageHeight) / 2;
                event.gc.drawImage(image, x, y);

            }
        });
```

after this I am able to see ImageICON LabelText ImageICON as shown below

[image]

But when I mouse over on the node only first image and text are highlighted and tool tip is coming for them. I want to highlight the third image also and want to bring the tool tip like other selection.

Comment: Are you using a JFace `TableViewer` or a plain SWT `Tree`?

Comment: Hi Rudiger I am using org.eclipse.jface.viewers.CheckboxTreeViewer

Comment: Most likely your paint code interferes with the JFace `LabelProvider` code. As a rule of thumb: don't mess with a widget when it is provided by a  JFace viewer. You should use an `OwnerDrawLabelProvider` instead.

Comment: Hi Rudiger, thanks for the input, I tried with OwnerDrawLabelProvider I am able to add image and text.. but  on mouse over on the image and text are not being high lighted and also I am getting an blue high lighted row after my first selection. Am i missing something here?

Comment: The blue background is the default handling of a line with `SWT.SELECTED` by the owner draw `erase` method.  You can override this.

Comment: Thanks Rudiger and greg for your  comments